# How should I write the error term for a weighted least-squares regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, weighted

If I run a weighted least-squares regression, where the errors are assumed to be independent and normally distributed but with unequal variance, how would I write the error term for the model. Would it be appropriate to write it something along the lines of:

\begin{align*}
Y_i&\sim\beta_0+\beta_1X_i+\varepsilon_i\\
\varepsilon_i&\sim N(0,\sigma^2w)
\end{align*}

Thank you.

Comment: If the variances are unequal, shouldn't they be subscripted? Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: Normally, one thinks of observations with larger weights having more, not less, influence on the solution.  Thus, the model usually is written as $\varepsilon_i \sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/w_i)$ or $\varepsilon_i \sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/w_i^2)$ (for inverse-variance weights, which is common).